# How could I use ajax to update buttons and counts without redirecting?

Tags: django, ajax, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to make like/dislike functionality so if a user is watching a video (for example) the page doesn't refresh and make them lose the progress in the video. I understand how to modify content of a `<div>` tag but have no idea how to deal with the logic that I would need to use to change the text/url of the button (example: if they click 'like' then the 'like' should become 'unlike' and the url attached to 'like' should be changed).

The way I've tried to tackle this is below, I haven't figured a way to code the logic into the replacement template yet and deleted what I had before so forgive me for not putting up the HTML.

handle_likes.js

```
(...)
// Handle button clicks
$(".like-btn").on('click', function(){
    console.log("Like button was clicked!"); // sanity check

    // Get the value of the original button
    if ($(".like-btn").val() == "not-liked") { 
        like_post();

    // I figured I could change the value to change the linked url
    }
    if ($(".like-btn").val() == "is-liked") {
        unlike_post();

    }

});
// Functions to handle likes/dislikes
function like_post(){
    console.log("Like post called...") // sanity check
    $.ajax({
        url: "posting/liking_post/",
        data: {
            post_id : $("#post_id").val(), // Need this to get the post
            post_type : $("#post_type").val() // This too
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $('.like-count').html(data); //Try to update the count of the likes on post
            $('.like-btn').html(data); // Try to change the like button
            },

        // Show error | display in console
        error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
            $('#results').html("<div class='alert-box alert radius' data-alert>Please contact an admin; We have encountered an error: "+errmsg+
                " <a href='#' class='close'>&times;</a></div>"); // add the error to the dom
            console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText); // provide a bit more info about the error to the console
        }
    });
};
(...)
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def like_post(request):
    """
    Checks if user already liked a post, if not then it will make a like object and assign it to the user and post
    """
    print(request.is_ajax())
    if request.is_ajax():
        post_type = request.GET.get('post_type')
        post_id = request.GET.get('post_id')

        if post_type and post_id:
            post = toolz.get_post(int(post_id), post_type)
        else:
            raise Exception("Post info not passed") # If like button clicked twice, no info is passed
        try:
            likes = list(Like.objects.filter(object_id=post_id))

            if len(likes) > 0:
                print("\n\n", likes, "\n\n") # debug
                users = list()
                for i in likes:
                    users.append(i.user)    

            if request.user in users:
                print("User has liked this post")
                return HttpResponse("Trying to like post twice...is a no no") # just a debug for myself

            else:
                like = Like(
                user=request.user,
                content_object=post
                )
                like.save()
                toolz.get_post(post_id, post_type, editing=True).update(like_count=F('like_count') + 1)
                like_count = post.like_count
                print("DEBUG 456 in like_post; user like list:", likes)
                user_liked = True
                return render(None, 'like_count.html' ,{'like_count': like_count, 'user_liked': user_liked})

        except Exception as e:
            print("\nSilent Exception; Error:", e)

    else:
        raise Exception("Request is not AJAX")
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I added two methods to the post classes that checked the like and dislike models for the object that is to be 'liked' and returned the users that are linked to it as a list. (method is below) I tried using `self.likes.filter(object_id=self.id)` because I have a ManyToMany field for the likes (Should I replace that with a GenericRelation?) but for some reason that didn't work so I just accessed the model directly.
Now I can handle everything through ajax on the same page in the same JavaScript file. Logic for if the user bypasses the template logic (trying to like or dislike more than once...even though they would get a `UNIQUE constraint failed` Exception....Do I even need the logic for that?) is in the view.

Being so new to JavaScript, this is a big win for me :D

Class method

```
    def get_liked_users(self):
        all_likes = Like.objects.filter(object_id=self.id)
        users = list()
        for like in all_likes:
            users.append(like.user)
        return users
```

Then inside of the templates I did this...

```
<!--Like stuff-->
{% if request.user not in post.get_liked_users %}
        <button class="like-post-btn" value="not-liked">Like</button>
{% else %}
        <button class="like-post-btn" value="is-liked">Unlike</button>
{% endif %}
        <div class="like-count">{{post.like_count}}<div>

<!--Dislike stuff-->
{% if request.user not in post.get_disliked_users %}
        <button class="dislike-post-btn" value="not-disliked">Dislike</button>
{% else %}
         <button class="dislike-post-btn" value="is-disliked">Undislike</button>
{% endif %}
        <div class="dislike-count">{{post.dislike_count}}</div>
```